# Help finding hole in logic with Lambert $W$-function.

Tags: logarithms, lambert-w

Can you guys help me find the error in this. If we start with

$≥1$ and $k$ is an integer and we know that $k > \ln(k)$, then

$$^>$$
$$1>^{−}$$
$$−1<−^{−}$$

But we know that the lowest value of $k$ is one. Plugging this in gives us

$$−1<−^{−1}≤−^{−}$$
Solving for $k$ with the Lambert $W$-function gives us,
$(−^{−1})≤−$.

But $(−^{−1})=−1$, so we have
$$−1≤−$$
then adding $1$ and $k$ to both sides gives us $≤1$, but we started with $≥1$, so this would seem to indicate that $=1$ exactly. This is clearly false, but I can't find the hole in the logic.

Comment: You need to use the [non-principal branch](https://dlmf.nist.gov/4.13) $W\text{m}$ of $W$ which is a decreasing function. It will give you $ - 1 \ge  - k \Longleftrightarrow 1 \le k$.

Comment: @Gary Why do I need to use one version of the Lambert W function over the other? I get that I do, just curious if it would be the same case in all similar instances. Or if it's more something that's going to be case by case. 

On a different note, is it all decreasing functions which flip from greater than to less than and vise versa?

Comment: If you use the other branch you establish that $k>\ln k$ holds for $0<k\leq1$. And indeed if $f$ is decreasing on $[a,b]$ then for $a\leq x<y\leq b$, $f(x)\geq f(y)$.

Comment: Is that strictly true for the principal branch of W? What if I have something like

$$e^a - e^b > a - b$$

Where I want to know for what $a$ this is true.

$$e^a > (a - b + e^b)$$
$$1 > (a - b + e^b)e^{-a}$$
$$e^{b - e^b} > (a - b + e^b)e^{-a + b - e^b}$$
$$-e^{b - e^b} < -(a - b + e^b)e^{-a + b - e^b}$$

If I use the W function here, do I use the principle branch or the non-principle branch?

$$ W(-e^{b - e^b}) \ ? -(a - b + e^b)$$
$$ W(-e^{b - e^b}) \ ? - a + b - e^b$$
$$ a \ ? - W(-e^{b - e^b}) + b - e^b$$

Depending on which branch is used, that will change the answer.